# How to convert a json object to pandas json type column

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a code like below

```
import json
import ast
import pandas as pd

data = [[110636, [{'Name': 'cd0', 'id': '1'}, {'Name': 'cd1', 'id': '2'}, {'Name': 'cd2', 'id': '3'}]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','json_load'])
df['json_load'] = df['json_load'].astype(str).apply(json.loads)
print(df)
exploded = df.explode("json_load")
df = pd.json_normalize(exploded['json_load'])
```

While executing the code, I am getting error like `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)` even though it's a valid JSON

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think yo want `json.dumps`?

Comment: No I want to do some json operations after that,I have updated the post

Comment: `df['json_load'] = df['json_load'].apply(json.loads)` will trigger an error. Can you be explicit about which part of you code builds the example input and which part is your attempt? Also, remove `if __name__ == "__main__":` it's useless here.

Comment: @mozway I have edited it.This is the code I am trying to run

Comment: You code still fails, do you want `data = [[110636, '[{"Name": "cd0", "id": "1"}, {"Name": "cd1", "id": "2"}, {"Name": "cd2", "id": "3"}]']]`?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to rewrite your line with JSON to this one:

`data = [[110636, '[{"Name": "cd0", "id": "1"}, {"Name": "cd1", "id": "2"}, {"Name": "cd2", "id": "3"}]']]`

First, JSON object must be str, bytes, or bytearray, not list. Thus, add a single quote to make this list a string. 
Second, JSON format is expected to have double quoting for your name properties.

If you run your code with mine correction, the output would be like this:

```
  Name id
0  cd0  1
1  cd1  2
2  cd2  3
```

On the other hand, if that `[[110636, [{'Name': 'cd0', 'id': '1'}, {'Name': 'cd1', 'id': '2'}, {'Name': 'cd2', 'id': '3'}]]]` is the exact format of your data, try this:

`data = [[str(item).replace("'", "\"") for v1 in data for item in v1]]`

before applying `json.loads` to your df.

The reason you actually getting an error message is that both id, which is 110636, and the following list have to be in quotes, as those are JSON properties

Comment: Yes That's what I want to achieve,but the requirement is such it's coming with single quotes

Comment: @Hannah so you're getting data from somewhere, as is?

Comment: @Hannah I updated the answer. If you are getting your JSON in that format, you just gotta convert every property into str